# Favoriting / Unfavoriting jobs response time pretty slow (async: false?)

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

The amount of time it takes to "favorite" or "unfavorite" a job posting seems to take too long.  Upon inspection of clicking favorite and then trying to proceed with what I am doing such as triggering another event seems to be blocked.  It appears that maybe `async: false` is being used blocking the UI from further requests.

Propose to change this such that there is no blocking upon clicking on other items in so jobs.  For instance, add 2-3 favorites.  Now try to unfavorite one of these jobs while at the same time favoriting another job listing.  The result is you are blocked from favoriting another job until the other event is fully complete.  This can be avoided by using some sort of promise in javascript.

[As @carpetsmoker notes, this is of course happening on the jobs overview page not the job listing pages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319880/favoriting-unfavoriting-jobs-response-time-pretty-slow-async-false?noredirect=1#comment327428_319880)

Comment: This only seems to be a problem when clicking the stars on the jobs overview page, but not when clicking "Add to favourites" on a job listing page.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker - Simple reason is, in the job listing page you aren't building your favorites div found on the right side.  On the job overview page you are building that little div..hence the slowness, but still I think 2 things need to come out of this.  Get rid of that div entirely and show the favorites within a page just like Q&A favorites.  Secondly, don't rely on async:false as the UI is being blocked upon event trigger.

Comment: ...And `async: false` has been deprecated, at least in jQuery, since version 1.8. So, like, *forever* in internet years... :)